# Using parse on a web hosting

Tags: android, parse-platform, backend, parse-server

let me ask my question with an example:

Assume that I have some PHP files for my android app that I put it on `000webhost[dot]com`; so, my question is how can I use parse (`parseplatform[dot]org`) in this situation?

- I'm new in backend, so I'm sorry if this question is stupid!
- For some reason I can't use back4app, aws, etc.
- Don't worry about php language, if it's necessary I can write it in another language. (my backend logic is not complex)

Comment: would you mind to share why you can't use back4app or aws?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a simple web-site with simple backend logic, I'd do that using Express.js. Since Parse Server is essentially an Express.js middleware, you can use the same process to serve both Parse Server and the web-site.

If you prefer to use a different technology, Parse Platform provides many different sdks (https://parseplatform.org/#sdks) that you can use for many different backend technologies (including PHP), or you can connect directly to the REST (https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/) or GraphQL (https://docs.parseplatform.org/graphql/guide/) apis using any client.

Comment: Thank you, yes it's simple in the backend.
So, if I use its android sdk in my app, what about parse-dashboard and parse-server? How can I use these, I mean back4app has environment for mange everything but in the 000webhost how can I do my things?

Answer (score 0):

When I asked this question, I didn’t know what exactly should I search until I found [this amazing article](https://blog.back4app.com/firebase-alternatives/). This article opened my mind, the most helpful thing that I found there, was this:

1. Parse is more flexible. Given the freedom to host Parse on the
   server of your choice.
2. You can choose the self-hosting option and deploy your Parse project
   on your selected server, such as Digital Ocean.

And then I found [this awesome video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yhc_fzSi0kk).

Now I can run **parse** on my own server (vps or cloud).

I know the title of this question may not be clear, but I don’t want to change it, because someone like me doesn’t know the right keyword for research.

Hope this help someone else too.